# HAProxy: multiple websites, but only one of them needs to use ALL backends

Tags: haproxy

I currently have a HAproxy loadbalancer setup with 2 backends for a total of 3 websites. One of the websites needs an extra server (a new backend, backend #3), but the others don't have to use this backend. Is there any way to do this? Sadly, I was not able to figure this out using the documentation. Config added. New backend is going to be .77. Thanks!

```html
global
 log /dev/log local0
 log /dev/log local1 notice
 chroot /var/lib/haproxy
 stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
 stats timeout 30s
 user haproxy
 group haproxy
 maxconn 2000
 daemon

 # Default SSL material locations
 ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
 crt-base /etc/ssl/private

 # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
 # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
 #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
 ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
 ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

 # use 7 of 8 cores, bind stats to the 7th. We want one core for OS and stuff :)
 
 nbproc 7
        cpu-map 1 1
        cpu-map 2 2
        cpu-map 3 3
        cpu-map 4 4
        cpu-map 5 5
        cpu-map 6 6
        cpu-map 7 7
        stats bind-process 7

defaults
 log global
 mode http
 option httplog
 option dontlognull
 option  forwardfor
 option  http-server-close
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
 errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
 errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
 errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
 errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
 errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
 errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
 errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


listen stats 192.168.3.78:1936
 stats enable
 stats uri /

frontend www-http
 bind 1.2.3.4:80
 bind 192.168.3.78:80
 reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
 bind-process 1
 default_backend www-backend

frontend www-https
 bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/1.full-pem crt /etc/ssl/private/2.full-pem crt /etc/ssl/private/3.full-pem 
 reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
 option forwardfor
 bind-process 2 3 4 5 6
 default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
 redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
        cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
 server www-1 192.168.3.75:80 check cookie www-1
 server www-2 192.168.3.74:80 check cookie www-2
```

Comment: Could you add your configuration to your post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note about the word "backend": you used it in your question to describe the service that will get forwarded requests. To avoid confusion, I'll use here `server` for that, `backend` will be a group of `server` (to match the HAProxy terms).

You need two `backend` blocks, one with two `server` the other with three. In your `frontend`, use the hostname to choose the correct one:

```
frontend www-http
  [...]
  acl host_website3 hdr(host) -i website3.com         # match the new website
  use_backend www-backend-with3 if host_website3      # send it to the correct backend
  default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server www-1 192.168.3.75:80 check cookie www-1
  server www-2 192.168.3.74:80 check cookie www-2

backend www-backend-with3                             # new backend here
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server www-1 192.168.3.75:80 check cookie www-1
  server www-2 192.168.3.74:80 check cookie www-2
  server www-3 192.168.3.77:80 check cookie www-3     # with a new server here
```